# Can IRA contributions be recharacterized multiple times

Tags: united-states, income-tax, ira, recharacterization

Are there limitations on *recharacterizing* (not converting) IRA contributions such that you could not re-characterize a contribution multiple times?

Recharacterized an Roth IRA to a traditional IRA, only to afterwards realize that was not the best thing to do.  Looking at [Publication 509-A](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p590a/ch01.html#en_US_2014_publink1000230671), I see there are restrictions on on recharacterizing after a conversion, however, I do not see anything restricting recharacterizing after a recharacterization.

I am still within the window to be able to file an amended tax return.

---

**Why I recharacterized:**  I will be in the Peace Corps for the next 27 months and will have little taxable income.  The Peace Corps pointed out that there can be tax advantages in converting IRAs while serving and having low income.  I recharicterized my contribution Roth contribution so I could do so.

**Why I want to re-recharacterize:**  The fees for maintaining the IRA are higher than I anticipated, eating into any tax savings I expected to realize.  Additionally, transferring the IRA to somewhere I could hold it for free has a high exit fee.

Comment: Can you elaborate? i.e. give an example of exactly what you propose to do.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I have added context with respect to what I am aiming to accomplish

Comment: How is the recharacterization going to solve your problem? Roth IRA and Traditional IRA have different fees? And they're not $0? Just roll over to a normal broker.

Comment: @litteadv, the Roth IRA is grandfathered in to not having the fees